# Query array of nested documents for highest value of field

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to query an array of nested documents in mongodb, and also get the highest value of a particular field in that nested document. (In java)

Here is an example of the document structure, where I want to find the largest value of the `"value"` field in the array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("526d89571cd72ce9dbb6b443"),
    "array" : [ 
         {"text" : "this is a nested document", "value" : 1 },
         {"text" : "this is another nested document", "value" : 2 }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try modern approach - [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/):

**1)** Find maximum array 'value' for all elements in collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $group: { _id: "$_id", value: { $max: "$array.value" } } }
]);
```

**2)** Find maximum array 'value' for specified element:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId("526d89571cd72ce9dbb6b443") } },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $group: { _id: null, value: { $max: "$array.value" } } }
]);
```

Use real collection name instead of `collection` in these examples.

Some information on how to use aggregation in Java MongoDB driver: [Java Driver and Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/).

Comment: Those both return `{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }`?

Comment: @August, since you didn't specify real collection name in your question, I simply named it `collection`. But you must use real collection name. (I've added this to answer)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this pretty easily with a MongoDB map/reduce. Here's the map/reduce I'd write:

```
map = function() { 
  for (var a in this.array) { 
    emit('value', a.value); 
  }
};

reduce_max = function(key, values) {
    var max = values[0];
    values.forEach(function(val) {
        if (val > max) max = val;
    })
    return max;
};
```

and, while I don't have a java dev environment ready to go, [here's an article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/mapreduce-with-mongodb.html) on how to do Map/Reduce queries in Java.