# Getting enclosing document from aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb

This is sort of an expansion on this post: [Query array of nested documents for highest value of field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624047/query-array-of-nested-documents-for-highest-value-of-field)

Say I have this document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("526d89571cd72ce9dbb6b443"),
    "array" : [ 
         {"text" : "this is a nested document", "value" : 1 },
         {"text" : "this is another nested document", "value" : 2 }
    ]
}
```

And I'm aggregating it with:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId("526d89571cd72ce9dbb6b443") } },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $group: { _id: null, value: { $max: "$array.value" } } }
]);
```

How would I get the document in the array `"array"` that contains the result of the aggregation -  `"value" : 2`. I would like to be able to get this:

```
{"text" : "this is another nested document", "value" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do an `$unwind` and then a `$sort`. If you do that, you can use `$first`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId("526d89571cd72ce9dbb6b443") } },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $sort: { "array.value": -1 } },
    { $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        text: { $first: "$array.text" }, 
        value: { $max: "$array.value" } 
    } }
]);
```

Your result is then:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "text" : "this is another nested document",
            "value" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you also need the original `_id`, then you could also do this in the `$group`:

```
{ $group: { 
    _id: null, 
    original_id: { $first: "$_id" },
    text: { $first: "$array.text" }, 
    value: { $max: "$array.value" } 
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query will solve your problem.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: new ObjectId("526d89571cd72ce9dbb6b443") } },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    { $group: { _id: "$array.text", value: { $max: "$array.value" } } },
    {$limit : 1}
]);
```

This will print the result as follows :

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "this is another nested document",
        "value" : 2
    }
]
```

Comment: It is working. The only differece is, I set the text data into the _id field not in a text field.